# Cant send non-english characters to PDF

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iframe, report

I am having trouble rendering non-english characters in a pdf that gets generated as a blob using node.js and displayed in an iframe element. 
[First line and client Name is supposed to be cyrillic characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPoXu.png)  I am using fluentreports which mentions nothing about the character set that it can handle. Here is the code that receives the blob from my server.

```js
if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var file = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        
        this.setState({
          pdf: fileURL
        })

      }
    });
    xhr.send(formDataString);
  }
 

  render() {
   
    return (
    <div> 
     
      <div style = {{ margin: '0'}} className = "container"> 
        <div  className= "jumbotron">
         
          {this.state.form ? <DateForm onChange = {this.handleChange} onChange2 = {this.handleChange2} onSubmit = {this.onSubmit} date1 = {this.state.date1} date2 = {this.state.date2}/> : null} 
          
        {this.state.pdf? <iframe  style = {{width:"100%" ,height: "800"}} src = {this.state.pdf}> </iframe> : null}
        
        </div>

        
      </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question and hopefully help someone else. Fluentreports allows to register fonts. I am generating my pdf on the server side so here is what needs to be done. Download [Arial Unicode MS](http://www.myfontfree.com/download-arial-unicode-ms-zip36926.htm) and from a static point, serve it to the location where you render your report as follows.

```js
// Create a Report   
  var rpt = new Report(res,({fontSize: 10,font: 'Bulgarian'}))
        .titleHeader(hh)
        .margins(40)
        .data( {})               // Add some Data (This is required) 
  

 rpt.registerFont("Bulgarian", {normal: './server/static/ARIALUNI.ttf'});
```